# Causality Tracking Option in Extended Events Seems To Be AWOL

Tags: causality

There used to be a checkbox for causality tracking in Extended Events. I don't see it anymore (SSMS 18.8) nor see anything about when where it would have been removed. Anyone know anything?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  The checkbox is still there, but below the bottom of the dialog window.  Increase the size of the dialog window until it's visible.  Perhaps there should have be a scrollbar.